# A young punk gets mentored by a classy old gentlemen

Tags: identify-this-movie

I've been trying for ages to find the title of a film that I watched once when I was a child. The story, as I remember it, goes like this:

A relatively young, 20-30-ish guy, very hot-headed, but with no manners, money, etc, is the protagonist. The film opens with him, on a three-wheel motorcycle, stopped at a traffic light, next to him pulls another guy in a very expensive car. The light turns yellow, our guy revs his funny motorcycle, it stands on its back wheels and when the lights turns green, he's already storming ahead.

Cut to the next scene which I remember: somehow an old gentleman has taken our guy under his wing. He's classy, somewhat rich (I think) and tries to teach him some manner. What grabbed my attention was when the old man - who I'm pretty confident was named Max and that had something to do with the movie title - was showing the young one how to peel an apple with a fork and a knife in one single motion.

The film ended with the hero winning the heart of a woman, there was a pearl necklace and a swimming pool.

I'm almost positive that the movie was from the US, it might date somewhere around the 90s, but could be even 80s. As I stated above, I think there might be the word Max in the title.

Does any of this ring any bells for you?

Comment: I tried using imdb's advanced search to find it but details that would help are unknown to me but known to you, like whether it was black or white, what other features there were in the film etc. Take a look: http://www.imdb.com/search/title

Comment: The film was definitely in colour, and all the main characters/actors were white. Other than that, I really don't know what to add. There were a couple of scenes which stuck to my mind and I've described them above, but that's all I can remember.

Comment: There's an obscure 1992 movie called [Max & Jeremie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0104830/combined) where a socially awkward Jeremie (Christopher Lambert) is mentored by older gentleman Max (Philippe Noiret). But they're both hitmen and I don't think *anything else* fits. :(

Comment: I found some screenshots of the movie - it definitely is not the one I remember :(

Comment: @zkvvoob OK, don't despair, I know what you're after. :) Putting it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [Count Max](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101612/combined) (AKA Il Conte Max) from 1991. [From the NY Times](http://www.nytimes.com/movies/movie/211031/Il-Conte-Max/overview):

> Years before, the millionaire Pierre (Alain Flick) destroyed the wealthy nobleman Count Max's fortune. In the present, Alfredo (Christian De Sica), a restless young mechanic who resembles the count, has fallen in love with a model (Ornella Muti) and wants some new adventure in his life. In return for his agreement to get revenge on the Count's old foe, **he gets lessons in how to behave like the count himself.** He tracks down the model, woos her successfully, and persuades her to join forces with him to go to Morocco and confront the nefarious millionaire.

In the beginning of the film, Alfredo, on his three-wheel bike, races someone once the light changes, and later, Max teaches him how to peel an *orange* with a knife and fork. It's Italian, though, not US. Couldn't find a trailer, but here's a clip with the protagonist: